# Dynamic list render in angular 5

Tags: angular

I am having an array and I want to show a list such that the current page is divided into 3 pre tags and all the elements of the list should be distributed in those 3 tags something like this[image: Something like this]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides **slice** pipe with **ngFor** loop. Hope below will help you :

**TS Code :**

```
// This is your results array
    steps = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Step 1'
        },
        // .... Add more steps
    ];

    // As you have 3 colums I have put 3 static here.
    getMinSlice(columnIndex) {
        return Math.ceil((this.steps.length / 3) * (columnIndex - 1));
    }

    getMaxSlice(columnIndex) {
        return Math.ceil((this.steps.length / 3) * columnIndex);
    }
```

**HTML code :**

```
       <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div *ngFor="let b of steps | slice:getMinSlice(1):getMaxSlice(1)">{{b.name}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div *ngFor="let b of steps | slice:getMinSlice(2):getMaxSlice(2)">{{b.name}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div *ngFor="let b of steps | slice:getMinSlice(3):getMaxSlice(3)">{{b.name}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes. I have tested it.